# Spring Data JPA Non-key field references in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

[EntityDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szA0E.png) How to Event(id) refererences to CurriculumVitae(event_id) and FamilyMember(id) refererences to CurriculumVitae(family_member_id)
My code is :
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CurriculumVitaes")
`public class CurriculumVitae implements Serializable` {
/**
*
*/
`private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`
`@Id`
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`
`private Long id;`

```
@Column(name = "identity_card_number")
private String identityCardNumber;

@Column(name = "place_for_identity_cards")
private String placeForIdentityCards;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;

@Column(name = "ethnic")
private String ethnic;

@Column(name = "religion")
private String religion;

@Column(name = "family_composition_after_land_reform")
private String familyCompositionAfterLandReform;

@Column(name = "family_member")
private String familyMember;

@Column(name = "education_level")
private String educationLevel;

@Column(name = "language")
private String language;

@Column(name = "qualification")
private String qualification;

@Column(name = "type_of_education")
private String typeOfEducation;

@Column(name = "specialized_training")
private String specializedTraining;

@Column(name = "health_situation")
private String healthSituation;

@Column(name = "tall")
private String tall;

@Column(name = "weight")
private String weight;

@Column(name = "occupation_or_qualification")
private String occupationOrQualification;

@Column(name = "ranks")
private String rank;

@Column(name = "current_salary")
private String currentSalary;

@Column(name = "date_of_enlistment")
private Date dateOfEnlistment;

@Column(name = "date_of_demobilization")
private Date dateOfDemobilization;

@Column(name = "reason")
private String reason;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =         FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Event> event;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "curriculumVitae", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<FamilyMember> familyMemberList;
```

}

But FamilyMembers(curriculum_vitae_id) references to CurriculumVitae(id)*

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "FamilyMembers")
`public class FamilyMember implements Serializable {`

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "occupation")
private String occupation;

@Column(name = "august_revolution")
private String augustRevolution;

@Column(name = "resistance_war_against_French_colonialism")
private String resistanceWarAgainstFrenchColonialism;

@Column(name = "activities_from_1955")
private String activitiesFrom1955;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "curriculum_vitae_id", referencedColumnName =    "family_member_id")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
private CurriculumVitae curriculumVitae;
```

}

Comment: We don´t understand what you asking for.

Comment: I echo what @CaptainPyscho is saying, it's unclear what you are asking here.